# Add item to Highcharts legend?

Tags: highcharts, legend

Is it possible to add an item to the Highcharts legend?

I have added a custom marker at a specific point in my line chart and would like to explain to the user what this marker indicates, so ideally I would add this as an additional item to the legend area.

Comment: Please share the answer. How to add multiple items to legend like "In Range" and "Out of Range" ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to add that custom marker as a separate series, instead of within the original series.

```
{
 name: 'Special Point',
 marker: { enabled: true },
 data: [[4,9]] 
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/123/

[image: custom point in legend]